# UNIX sockets: How to check if TCP stream is closed for reading or EOF?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcpclient, eof

I am writing a simple client which reads binary data through a TCP stream.
Since the file is sent part-by-part I have a loop similar to this one:

```
while (1 /* Maybe a check for EOF or if the socket is closed here ? */) {
  ssize_t bytes_red = recv(
  if (bytes_read <= 0) // not working properly ?
    break;
  ...
}
```

The reading is done via recv() method, which returns the number of bytes received.
The idea is obviously to read data as long the TCP stream is opened, but it seems the above approach does not work for me.

Any other ideas? What is a clean way to read from socket until the stream is closed or EOF is encountered?

**EDIT**: The above approach works fine, I had a bug elsewhere.

Comment: "Encounter an EOF" in this situation is identical to "the socket is closed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`recv()` returns 0 if the socket was properly closed, -1 if there was an error. So, you read until `recv()` returns `<=0`. Your posted code snippet looks correct - why do you think it's not working for you? What happens, what did you expect?

If your socket is non-blocking, you will also have to handle the case where `recv()` returns -1 and `errno` is set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. This means that the socket is still alive and well, but there's no more data right now.

Comment: I tried this, but as I said it does not seem to be working when I send random binary data. Are you 100% sure this is the right way?

Comment: @leden: Yes. You will additionally have to handle specific error codes if your socket is non-blocking, but the above *is* the right way.

Comment: @leden: is it a nonblocking socket? What flags are passed to `recv`?

Comment: No, it is a blocking socket, no flags are passed.

Comment: @leden: Likely you have another bug then. `recv()`'s behavior is well defined, and it works.

Comment: Ok, I found the bug elsewhere. Thanks.